# Azure DevOps - Android - build agen on my server

Tags: android-studio, azure-devops

Helo,

I have build agent pool install on my server. I install Java SDK and Android Studio. Command **gradlew assembleDebug** is working on server.

When I run build Queue on Azure DevOps on my server i have error:

```
Job issues · 1 error
No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
 java
 JDK
 AndroidSDK
 Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.116.0



##[Error 1]
No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:
 java
 JDK
 AndroidSDK
 Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.116.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands:

According to the error description, it indicates that the build task can't find the corresponding agent for job.

I recommend that you could have a try to do following things:

1. Make sure you  choose the correct private agent([self-host agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=vsts#install))
2. Add all of tool paths to the environment variable and make sure that all of these tools could be global access  in the command console.
3. You also could have a try to remove some of demands to check which are not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to run on your own "self hosted" agent you can also try the macOS agents offered by Microsoft. Those seem to have both the iOS and the Android build tools available.